# JavaFX how to access Label from another function

Tags: java, javafx

I have got a label in my scene and i want to change it's text.I have created this following function for that

```
public static void updateValue() {
    stage.getScene().getRoot();
}
```

I was planning that after getting the root of the Scene i'll be able to access it's children by `getChildren`,but to my surprise that function didn't show up.Only function with similar name was `getChildrenUnmodifiable` and that function is no good to me.So how can i access Label from another function?

Comment: Why do you need to access it that way, and why is `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` any less useful than `getChildren()`?

Comment: @James_D description of `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` is `read-only access to this parent's children ObservableList`,but i don't need a read-only access because i have to edit it

Comment: The list is unmodifiable, not its elements.

Comment: @James_D oh i see,but how do i access the label after that?

Comment: It returns a list, just `get(...)` it from the list in the usual way (though, again, this seems like a really strange way to go about changing the text of a label; you should not need to navigate through the scene graph from the stage like this).